# Timeshift Problem - filling hard drive

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I am using `Ubuntu Gnome 17.04`. I have been using `Timeshift` successfully, however, I decided to exclude a few folders (like steam games) to help reduce the amount of space the backups take.

I removed the snapshots and checked my disk usage. To be expected, my disk usage was much lower about 76 GB. I excluded the folders and began the new snapshot. During the process, I realized that I had excluded the wrong steam folder and hence, I canceled it. It now says that

```
There is not enough space to create a snapshot
```

When I look at `Disks` application it shows that my SSD is at about 205 GB. When I look at the `Disk Usage Analyzer`, it shows that it is still using  around 76 GB. Could there be some hidden folder where the snapshot have been saved, when I cancelled the process? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I've realized what was happening. It is obvious now, but for others that are ignorant to Ubuntu as I am; There is another trash folder in the root directory.  I installed k4dirstat (which seems to be better than "Disk Usage Analyzer") and see that I have 114.56 GBs sitting at /.local/share/Trash.  Problem solved.  Thanks all if you had attempted to help!